# Having the model in other project of the same solution

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I build a solution that contains two projects, one for the UI and another for the Data model

[image]

I added a reference to the DataModel in the UI project, and it allows me to work with the model without compiling errors, but when I execute, it throws an error saying that there's no connection string.

The question is, do I have to copy the connection string used in the DataModel solution to the UI project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer would be yes, you need to copy the connection string: The only app.config that is used is the one retrieved from the project you execute, because an application only *needs* one configuration file.

There are some other things you could do:

- If you have multiple projects sharing the same configuration settings, you can set up an app.config in your solution folder, and link to that configuration file from every project under that solution.
- Removing the dependency to the app.config from your libraries altogether, and ensuring that only the running project uses the configuration settings, "using" your library with those settings.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I like the last option; but, how can I do that? I didn't create it in the first place, how can I be sure that when I create a new app.config file, all my libraries will use it, the don't have a "using app.config;" anywhere. And where should I put it?

Comment: What I meant by "using" the configuration is that the running application passes on the connection string to your library(Like instantiating a database context/connection with said connection string), so that the library does not do this itself anymore.

Comment: And how can I implement the second option: "set up an app.config in your solution folder, and link to that configuration file from every project under that solution"

Comment: You place the app.config in your solution folder and maintain it there. You can read how to set up a linked file here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234